# UWP debug/release error with ntdll.dll for LED detection

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm writing a UWP program to detect colors from LEDs, this program runs on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 IoT with attached display.

What the program does is take a reference image with the LED turned off, then take a image from the LED turned on.

Both images are converted to the same pixelformat and then are cropped to a smaller size, in which only the LED is shown (both the reference and the lighted LED).

Then those picture parts are converted to grayscale which is followed by creating a difference picture of the two, so that only pixels that changed from the reference to the lighted LED are shown.

To do so I use the NuGet-Package portable.AForge.imaging. The code is shown below.

```
            LEDBildNeu = LEDBild.Clone(PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            ReferenzbildNeu = Referenzbild.Clone(PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            Crop cropping = new Crop(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y), 100, 100));

            CroppedLED = cropping.Apply(LEDBildNeu);
            CroppedReferenz = cropping.Apply(ReferenzbildNeu);

            Grayscale grayscale = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
            GrayscaleReferenz = grayscale.Apply(CroppedReferenz);
            GrayscaleLED = grayscale.Apply(CroppedLED);
            
            Difference difference = new Difference(GrayscaleReferenz);
            Differenzbild = difference.Apply(GrayscaleLED);
```

This code works fine as long as I'm in debug mode, all of the functions are working.
However when I change to release mode, I get this error while building:

> 1>C:\Users\morsch.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.2\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): warning :       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'ntdll.dll!memcpy' for method 'System.Byte* AForge.SystemTools.memcpy(System.Byte*, System.Byte*, System.Int32)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisify those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.
>
> 1>C:\Users\morsch.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.2\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): warning :       MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'ntdll.dll!memset' for method 'System.Byte* AForge.SystemTools.memset(System.Byte*, System.Int32, System.Int32)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisify those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.

When I run the code in release mode and get to the part where the difference picture is created, I get the exception

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Unresolved P/Invoke method 'memcpy!ntdll.dll' from this method. Please look for this method in build warnings for more details.'

[According to this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/mt186422(v=vs.85).aspx) 'memset' and 'memcpy' are not supported by UWP. My questions now are:

Why does the program run in debug mode without any problems even when those two entry points are not supported, but as soon as i turn to release mode I get the exceptions?

Is there a workaround for the problem?

I already tried to use

```
        [DllImport("ntdll.dll", EntryPoint = "memset")]
```

and

```
        [DllImport("ntdll.dll", EntryPoint = "memcpy")]
```

But either I did it wrong or it just don't work that way.

I know I could just program a workaround in which I check the pixels manually and create a new image, but I wanted to solve that problem if possible.

Comment: That ntdll.dll has an export for this function on your machine is an appcompat quirk that goes back to very early Windows versions.  It mattered back in the days when they had to squeeze an operating system and its apps in the amount of memory that was less than your splash screen bitmap.  But it does not in the kind of Windows versions that .NETNative targets, it knows the difference.  It is surely not the only problem with AForge, be sure to also run WACK.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, ill also do a WACK run ( and im sure this could show some more problems), but for now the coding is just a fun project for me. Thats why i try to get it to work with AForge. As i said, i could just drop the "difference" function and create the difference Picture my own, but im more into solving why it wont work that way.

Comment: You can select the "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" build setting with debug mode and test.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I already did that, but still there is no error in debug mode while it wont work in release mode.

I also found a solution to the problem, i will post it when i have some time later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which worked:

Instead of downloading the portable.AForge package with NuGet i downloaded the [portable.AForge](https://github.com/cureos/aforge) from GitHub.

Find the .cs-file called SystemTools.cs (located in AForge/Sources/Core/).
Open it with any .cs editing porgram, now search for all code like

```
#if !MONO
...
#else
```

and remove it.

This clears the use of memcpu() or memset() from ntdll.dll.
Save the SystemTools.cs, create the library and add the AForge-Package manually to the application.

After the change it worked without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the correct combination of directives can be a very frustrating and time consuming process.  Here is additional information that I received from Microsoft via email, hope this helps:

---

Helpful links:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-native-deep-dive-dynamic-features-in-static-code/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/runtime-directives-rd-xml-configuration-file-reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/runtime-directive-policy-settings

The analysis we do to get your application ready to be ahead of time compiled is quite extensive. We need to generate code for various generic types, reflection callable wrappers, serialization information, marshalling stubs etc etc. In come cases (as you could imagine) we end up generating more than is strictly necessary due to run away combinatorics. It’s completely possible that some fiddling with our heuristics can get you application to a place where it compiles without any loss of functionality.

Practically speaking, there’s two ways to manipulate the behavior of the compiler. One is through some of our compiler flags available through dropping elements into your csproj. The other is making edits to your applications Properties\Default.rd.xml file.

**Compiler flags**

There are a wide range of flags available but here’s a couple that may help out:

`<ShortcutGenericAnalysis>true</ShortcutGenericAnalysis>` - Can help stop runaway analysis of generic types and reduce overall generation requirements.

`<UseDotNetNativeSharedAssemblyFrameworkPackage>false</UseDotNetNativeSharedAssemblyFrameworkPackage>` - Eliminates one of the linking boundaries the compiler has to fight with. I actually suspect turning this off will make things worse not better but whole program optimizers are hard to reason about but rebuilds are cheap enough to try.

**Runtime Directives**

There’s lots of reading above but the tl;dr is that this file is read by the compiler and can contain lots of hints about what we want it to do or ignore etc. The overall syntax of the file is also included in the reading above but I don’t think we’re very clear about the one special directive that’s include by default:

```
<Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />
```

This directive says: “Please save/generate enough information so that all user types can be inspected and created via reflection.” Where ‘user types’ means any type in an assembly that isn’t signed with the .NET key token. So, basically everything that isn’t explicitly .NET Framework. This in leads to lots of bloat but also makes it so most folks don’t ever have to think about these things. In cases where we don’t have enough information, you’ll get runtime exceptions like MissingMetadataException or TypeLoadException or NullReferenceException. Each instance will require a bit of code inspection and fiddling with directives to get patched up. This can be an annoying a fragile process. All that said, the analysis engine is quite sophisticated and you’ll get lots and lots of things ‘for free’ without the special directive or any hassle. It’s entirely possible that your app runs great with just a little bit of tweaking.

Okay, the goal now is to remove this directive but still have a working application. There’s two approaches that have tradeoffs, so I’ll describe both and let you decide if either methodology suits you. Roughly here’s what the two workflows look like:

1. Start from nothing.

   a.    Remove the special *Application* directive

   b.    Build the app

   c.    If the build fails, email us, else…

   d.    Test the app and see if you hit any runtime errors

   e.    If you do you’ll need to look at the error location and see if adding some directives can help then head back to (b).

   f.    If you find no errors, you’re done! Hooray!
2. Start from everything

   a.    Remove the special *Application* directive

   b.    Get a list of the full set of dlls for your project, for example by inspecting here: obj[architecture]\Release\ilc\in

   c.    For each dll, add a Dynamic directive. They’ll look like: `<Assembly Name="ASSEMBLYNAMEWITHOUTEXTENTION" Dynamic="Required All"/>`

   d.    Comment out some subset of these libraries

   e.    Build the app

   f.    If the build fails again in RHBIND go to (d)

   g.    Test the app and see if you hit any runtime errors

   h.    If you do you’ll need to look at the error location and see if adding some directives can help then head back to (e)

   i.    If you find no errors, you’re done! Hooray!